# Solving for exponent with multiple bases

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-function

From a practical perspective, my question can be most easily considered as solving for time in a future-value type equation, but for two separate investments growing at different rates.  Say you have two savings accounts, one presently valued at $P_1$ and growing at a rate of $R_1$ (compounding annually), the other at $P_2$ growing at $R_2$.  Starting from the standard compounding future-value formula:
\begin{equation}
    F=P(1+R)^t
\end{equation}
you want to know how many years ($t$) will pass before their combined future value crosses a given threshold $X$ (*i.e.*, $X=F_1+F_2$):
\begin{equation}
    X = P_1(1+R_1)^{t} + P_2(1+R_2)^{t}
\end{equation}
Unfortunately, that is as far as I get.  How do you solve for $t$?

Note: in this case, I am not interested in answers directed to plotting the curve or knowing the incidental value of $t$ for a specific set of inputs, rather, I want to know how to recast the equation in the form of $t = ?$.

Thanks.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: "Basic information?"  I wish, Adobe; all four of those sites are written for folks who already have some familiarity with how to do it, and only need some quick pointers for less common things -- not for a noob.  I had to find and then read a good bit of Oetiker's "Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2e" to get my equations to work.  I also noticed that other commenters at those four sites observed that figuring out how to write formulae here is neither obvious nor easy.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you won't get an algebraic answer. You will need to do a numerical root finding approach. A nice upper bound is available by lowering the higher R to match the other, then back down to find the correct $t$